# Why does subtracting two UTC timestamps give "subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones"?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to compare a Pandas datetime to a Python datetime.

The code

```
cur_t = pandas.Timestamp.utcnow()
```

Gives:

```
Timestamp('2019-02-14 14:31:40.283415+0000', tz='UTC')
```

And the code

```
data_t=indata.data.loc[2000].last_time
```

Gives:

```
Timestamp('2019-02-14 14:28:32+0000', tz='UTC')
```

However, subtracting data_t from cur_t gives `TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones`

What is going on here? Why can't andas compare two times with the same timezone?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254408/timestamp-subtraction-of-time-arrays-with-different-timezones) might be helpful

Comment: I am also having the same problem: trying to subtract Timestamp('2020-03-26 15:04:05+0000', tz='UTC') from Timestamp('2020-03-26 15:04:05+0000', tz='UTC') gives "TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones"

Comment: @SushovanMandal which version of pandas? Using 1.0.3 I don't get this error

Comment: @Paul Pandas v0.25.3